# How to edit cells of dataframe

Tags: r, macos, edit

I can't seem to get the function `edit` to work.
With this toy data (as well as with my actual data):

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("hi", "there"),
  y = rnorm(2)
)
```

and `edit`:

```
library(utils)
edit(df)
```

I get this error:

> xcrun: error:
> invalid active developer path
> (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun Error in
> edit.data.frame(df) :
> X11 dataentry cannot be loaded In addition:
> Warning messages:
> 1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `b`.
> 2: Unknown
> or uninitialised column: `OtherData`.
> 3: Unknown or uninitialised
> column: `day`.
> 4: Unknown or uninitialised column: `day`.
> 5: Unknown
> or uninitialised column: `mean_dur`.
> 6: In system2("/usr/bin/otool",
> c("-L", shQuote(DSO)), stdout = TRUE) :
> running command
> ''/usr/bin/otool' -L
> '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules/R_de.so'' had
> status 1

**Two questions:**

1. How can I fix or avoid the error?
2. How can edits made with `edit` be made permanent?

Comment: Are you inside a shell session without explicit X-Forwarding (e.g. docker container or SSH)?. They can made permanent using just `df <- edit(df)`

Comment: I've no idea what a shell session or X_Forwarding would be? How can I find out if that is the case?

Comment: Does the shell command `xeyes` work?. It has to be because edit is a graphical app requiring the X Server.

Comment: How would the shell command exactly look like?

Comment: Just type the program name `xyes` in Bash, Zsh, etc. Install the program if it is not there. You must see a new window with eyes in it.

Comment: When installing `xeyes`in `R`, I get this: `install.packages("xeyes")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘xeyes’ is not available for this version of R`

Comment: Which Operating System are you using? It is not a R package. Just normal software you install.

Comment: Do you really wanna use the edit function at all? Doing so, your code is not reproducible anymore. The idea of R code to have a precise record of things you did with the data. I recommend to create new csv files using your preferred spreadsheet tool and then import then in R. For editing, use [`mutate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) and [`bind_rows`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html) for combining datasets.